# Cannot get CefSharp Chromium web brower to work on target PC

Tags: vb.net, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I have a Windows VB application developed in Visual Studio 2013 that incorporates a CefSharp Chromium web browser (version 86.0.241 using the NuGet packages). Target CPU is set to x86, the build output path is set to bin\x86\debug, Configuration is set to Active (debug) and the Platform is set to Active (x86). The web browser works great on the development machine, but when I deploy the app to the target machine (which is a server), the browser displays a blank screen and freezes.

The CefSharp support files are included in the deployment package (InnoSetup), but I'm confused on which version of VC++ redistributables I need to deploy.The CefSharp FAQ's state that with versions 65.0.0 and above, the minimum of VC++2015 needs to be deployed. I had the client install this version on the target machine (when I originally deployed this app, I did not include the VC++ redistributables), but the browser still does not work. Do I need to deploy a different version?

Any other ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Please help!

Larry

Here is a link to the .zip file containing the CEF debug.log files from the client's three servers (the three servers rotate based on demand):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/b3zjxxk79v9xl9b/DataMinerDebugLogs.zip?dl=0

Please let me know if any of these provides the reason why the Chromium browser is displaying only a blank page.

Thanks.

Details of the log entry mentioned in my last comment:
[1228/093028.760:INFO:CONSOLE(32)] "Refused to connect to 'https://collection.decibelinsight.net/i/13878/265573/c.json' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src https://qbonline.api.intuit.net https://cdn.decibelinsight.net https://api.segment.io 'self' https://*.intuit.com https://*.intuit.com:* https://*.intuitcdn.net:* https://hosted-shell-assets-us-west-2.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com wss://plugin-localhost.intuitcdn.net:* wss://plugin.intuitcdn.net:* https://*.intuit.net wss://*.msg.liveperson.net/ws_api/account/ https://*.objectstorage.liveperson.net/ https://scripts.neuro-id.com https://api.neuro-id.com https://logs.neuro-id.com".
", source: https://cdn.decibelinsight.net/i/13878/265573/di.js (32)

Code from Auth Class (the form that opens and displays the Chromium browser):

```
Imports Intuit.Ipp.OAuth2PlatformClient
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Web
Imports CefSharp
Imports CefSharp.WinForms


Public Class Auth
    Public WithEvents Browser As ChromiumWebBrowser
    Dim Settings As New CefSettings
    Private Sub Auth_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        oauthClient = New OAuth2Client(ClientID, ClientSecret, RedirectURL, "production")
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
        Dim scopes As List(Of OidcScopes) = New List(Of OidcScopes)()
        scopes.Add(OidcScopes.Accounting)
        authorizeURL = oauthClient.GetAuthorizationURL(scopes)
        Settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu")
        Browser = New ChromiumWebBrowser(authorizeURL)
        Me.Controls.Add(Browser)
        Browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    End Sub

    Private Sub Browser_AddressChanged(sender As Object, e As AddressChangedEventArgs) Handles Browser.AddressChanged
        Dim Str As String = Browser.Address
        If InStr(Str, "&realmID", CompareMethod.Text) Then
            Dim q = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Browser.Address)
            Dim Code As String = ""
            Dim RealmID As String = ""
            For Each key In q.Keys
                If InStr(key, "code") Then
                    Code = q.Item(key)
                ElseIf InStr(key, "realmId", CompareMethod.Text) Then
                    RealmID = q.Item(key)
                End If
            Next
            Call GetAuthTokens(Code, RealmID)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

The "Address_Changed" event can be ignored and the first 5 lines of the "Load" event all relate to another SDK used in the app, none of which is related to the Chromium browser.

Startup code added:

```
Shared Sub Main()
        'This sub executes first.
        Dim Settings As New CefSettings
        Settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu")
        cef.initialize(Settings)
        Application.EnableVisualStyles()
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(False)
        Application.Run(New MainMenu)
    End Sub
```

Comment: You need VC++ 2015 x86 or higher installed. If you didn't have vc++ installed the process would crash with an exception, so unlikely this is the problem. Does installing your innosetup  package work on your development machine? Another desktop computer? Just trying to identify if it includes all resources are included.

Comment: Also what version of server is it? Does Chrome run on the server?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the VC++ version. Yes, the InnoSetup package works on the development machine. That's what made me think it involved the VC++ redistributables. I will find out the server version and let you know. I didn't think it was necessary to have Chrome installed on the server if all the Chromium support files were installed.

Comment: It's not nessicary to have chrome installed,  it's purely a troubleshooting question. If Chrome doesn't run then a fundamental dependency is missing.

Comment: The server has Server 2012 R2 and Chrome installed. So I gather that a fundamental dependency is missing. What is the best way to check this? This app has several other Nuget packages installed with many dependencies of their own.

Comment: I checked all the files in my app's bin folder with those listed in this article https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Output-files-description-table-(Redistribution) and all are there.

Comment: If Chrome is installed and runs then all the fundamentals are there. Next is to check the log file see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#log-file servers often have poor graphics,  specially virtualised ones, might be you need to disable GPU acceleration. Log file hopefully tell us more.

Comment: Another question (and thanks for the great responses so far). When I rebuild this project, I get a list of dependent files saying they cannot be deleted because I do not have access. The files are in my \bin\x86\debug folder and are:
chrome_elf.dll

Comment: File list continued:
chrome_elf.dll
libcef.dll
cefsharp.Core.dll
cefsharp.dll
cefsharp.Winforms.dll
I there a setting I need to change to prevent this? If I close out of VS, manually delete these files, then I can reopen the project in VS and rebuild without issue.

Comment: Does the problem occur in a newer version of visual studio? Visual Studio (specifically msbuild) is responsible for copying the files. VS2017/2019 work as expected for me.

Comment: Are there any instances of CefSharp.BrowserSubProcess.exe still running after your application has exited? Possible you haven't cleanly shutdown your app.

Comment: Client uninstalled and then installed my revised deployment package (installer file) that also installs the VC++ distributables if needed. Still no luck, I have asked for the log file "debug.log" but on the development machine it all looks greek to me. How do I disable GPU acceleration? When I try to enter the line "Dim settings = new Cef.Settings", there is no "Cef" option available in my app. What am I missing?

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#cefsettings-and-browsersettings there is an example of disabling gpu acceleration. CefSettings is the name of the class.

Comment: I have added a link to the CEF debug.log files on my client's servers to the main body of my original post. Any help in interpreting these would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are there any errors? I don't download zip files on my tablet,  it's too inconvenient

Comment: Does the app run on any of the servers? Is it installed on all three? Running from a network drive is not supported (limitation of chromium).

Comment: The app is installed on all three servers. There appear to be two recurring errors with each session:
[1228/093657.939:ERROR:stun_port.cc(76)] Binding error response: class=4 number=1 reason=Unauthorized
[1228/093658.415:ERROR:rtc_error.cc(17)] RTCError: RTCErrorDetail is NONE
I have also added the details of a message from the debug log to my original post (too long for a comment) since it seems to relate to the OAuth2 that the app uses to request tokens.

Comment: I wouldn't expect either to cause a blank screen. Does loading a very simple web page like google.com work? Have you tested your installer on a machine other than your development machine with success? A win 10 virtual machine for example? Is the problem specific to these three machines? How are users connecting? Citrix? RDP? Are they physical machines running on bare metal or virtualised?

Comment: Client installed my app on a local PC and the browser worked perfectly. The users log onto one of the three servers with Remote Desktop (they never know which one because they rotate based on demand). The servers are virtual machines.

Comment: Have you tried disabling GPU acceleration? Does your app work if run direct from the server bypassing RDP?

Comment: I am trying to disable GPU acceleration, but I'm not sure I'm doing it right. In the Class Auth (the form that displays the browser), I have "Dim Settings = New CefSettings" and in the Load event of that form I have "Settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu")".
Are these in the right location? The example ends with "Cef.Initialize(settings) but I do not have "Cef" available in intellisense and I don't need to initialize Cef to make the browser work. Will the code I have added work without initializing? I apologize if I'm asking stupid questions.

Comment: You need to call Cef.Initialize when applying custom settings. The Cef class exists in the CefSharp namespace. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#initialize-and-shutdown has more information. As for when you call Cef.Initialize it needs to be called before you create your first ChromiumWebBrowser instance on the UI thread

Comment: In the article you referenced immediately above, it states "Cef.Initialize will be called for you implicitly if you create a new ChromiumWebBrowser instance and haven't already called Cef.Initialize". So if I have the line "Settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu")" before the line "Browser = New ChromiumWebBrowser([URL])", that should work, right?

Comment: If you call Cef.Initialize passing in a CefSettings instance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your last comment. I have included the code from the Auth Class at the end of my original post. Auth is the form that opens and displays the Chromium browser. This is the ONLY code that relates to CefSharp and the Chromium browser. Does this tell you anything. I'm at a loss here.

Comment: You need to call Cef.Initialize passing in a CefSettings instance before you create a ChromiumWebBrowser instance,  see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/cefsharp/86/CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms/Program.cs#L59 for an example of setting command line args. You can use the minimal example for testing purposes.

Comment: In the code I posted in the original post above, I declare the "Settings" and use it to disable gpu acceleration before declaring "Browser" as a new ChromiumWebBrowser. Will that work? Due to my lack of knowledge in this area, I would like some assurance that gpu acceleration WILL be disabled before deploying to the client servers for more testing. I appreciate very much the help you have provided so far.

Comment: No, you haven't called Cef.Initialize. I'm repeating myself here, please see my last comment. You can load chrome://gpu in the ChromiumWebBrowser instance to confirm it's disabled.

Comment: Intellisense in my app does not recognize the name "Cef". I downloaded the minimal example. In the Program.cs file containing the line "Cef.Initialize", "Cef" is red-underlined saying "The name 'Cef' does not exist in the current context."

Comment: Have you tried to compile the code? Ignore IntelliSense for now, rely on errors from the compiler.

Comment: See the startup code added above in the original post. When compiled, I get the error saying "'initialize' is not a member of 'cef'". What am I missing?

Comment: It's Cef.Initialize, where you've used all lowercase which is incorrect,  .Net languages are case sensitive.